# Create a component with toggle subcomponent in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, togglebutton

I am trying to create a component with multiples divs the html and some divs are toggled down when you press a button like in the jQuery toggle()Method in the link bellow: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp
I tried the code bellow the image but it doesn't work (I am using PrimeNg library but I am sure it could be done without). 
According to the image (sorry this is a very shame one but just for the exemple) so I would like when I click the button 1,2,3,4 or 5 it open the divs then if I click again I minified the div. What is the best method to do that without using JQuery?

[image]

Appliv2Component.ts:

```
export class AppliV2Component   { 


   @ViewChild('DisplayChildComponent') private changeComponent: DisplayChildComponent;

}

  display() {
        this.changeComponent;
        }
```

Appliv2Component.html:

```
<button pButton class="daydetail" type="button" label="Click" icon="fa-chevron-up" (onClick)="display()"></button>
```